# Is there a way to setup a Netbeans HTML5 and Web application project?

Tags: html, web-applications, netbeans, ide

The new Netbeans 7.3 Beta 2 adds a really nice feature for creating an HTML5 application.  It also provides a great way to create a Java Server based Web Application.  But there does not appear to be any way, within the Netbeans IDE, to take advantage of both technologies in one project.

Is there a way combine these two type of projects, so there is only one web directory structure with both the HMTL5, js, and web services files?

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely planned for the next release, but it is not yet possible in NetBeans 7.3. You can follow this enhancement request to see progress in this area: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222236. If you'd like to experiment with this, you can build NetBeans with the patch attached to that issue.

Comment: Not sure I'll get to the patch, but looking forward to the next release.  Thanks, Petr.